# Which way is faster , when receive a lot of packets?

Tags: networking, kernel

I have two ideas to handle the packet. 
1.I allocate  a memory pool and mmap into userspace, when packet is coming, I copy packet into the memory pool, then, userspace can access it. 
2.When packet is coming , I mmap the data of packet into userspace every time, then userspace can access this packet.

Which one is better, why?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the receiving application thread processing capability. How?

Assume you have a receive thread polling your `mmapped` descriptor ring sufficiently fast enough dequeuing the packets from the buffers allowing packets on the interface enqueue it at same pace. In this scenario definitely option 1 is the best.

When it comes to option 2, I feel per packet `mmap` invokes a system call which I think impacts performance compared to option 1 where you are creating buffer pool in user space at once calling only one `mmap` restricting to one system call.